How can I do add new Gamepad Name in common input base controller data
I had config common input base controller data in common input setting. but the gamepad name attribute only have Generic.
enter image description here
I have find the item source is from a special func,So I cant trace that.
enter image description here
enter image description here
What can I do if I want add new one about Xbox like lyra.
enter image description here
